# Como pegar valor de checkbox desmarcado usando JS?

Tags: javascript, html

Olá, pessoal, por favor, tenho o seguinte checkbox:

```
<ul class="nav">
   <li>
      <div>
         <label>Motivo de não informar o nome da mãe</label>
         <br/>
         <input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="checkMaeDesconhecida" name="nomeMaeDesc[1][]" value="1"> Desconhecido
         <input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="checkNaoTemMae" name="nomeMaeDesc[1][]" value="2"> Não tem
         <input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" checked id="checkMaeNaoInformada" name="nomeMaeDesc[1][]" value="3"> Não Informado
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Sei que esse comando JS pega o valor das minhas combos que estiverem selecionadas:

```
document.querySelector('.messageCheckbox:checked').value
```

porém, preciso que, caso nenhuma esteja selecionada, eu consiga pegar algum valor (tipo 0). Como faço isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta você selecionar todas as checkboxes selecionadas usando o `querySelectorAll` e verificando se o seu tamanho é maior que zero, da seguinte forma:

```
let checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.messageCheckbox:checked');
console.log(checkedBoxes > 0);
```

Segue exemplo funcional:

```js
function teste() {
  let checkedBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.messageCheckbox:checked');
  if (checkedBoxes.length > 0) {
    checkedBoxes.forEach(cb => console.log(`A checkbox ${cb.value} está selecionada`));
  } else {
    console.log('Nenhuma checkbox selecionada');
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
   <li>
      <div>
         <label>Motivo de não informar o nome da mãe</label>
         <br/>
         <input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="checkMaeDesconhecida" name="nomeMaeDesc[1][]" value="1"> Desconhecido
         <input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="checkNaoTemMae" name="nomeMaeDesc[1][]" value="2"> Não tem
         <input class="messageCheckbox" type="checkbox" checked id="checkMaeNaoInformada" name="nomeMaeDesc[1][]" value="3"> Não Informado
      </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<button onclick="teste()">Teste</button>
```

Comment: puxa, cara, era EXATAMENTE isso que eu precisava, funcionou muito bem! Brigadão!!!

Answer (score 4):

Basta usar a propriedade `checked`, por exemplo:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  // A propriedade `checked` retorna um `boolean`.
  console.log(input.checked);
});
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />

<button>Obter Valor</button>
```

Comment: valeu, cara, a sua solução acho que estava dentro também, mas achei o exemplo do Felipe mais adequado pro meu projeto, foi mais tranquilo de implementar... Brigadão!!